# Running lighttpd as a Windows service

Tags: windows, windows-services, webserver, lighttpd

Is there any up to date guide on running lighttpd as a Windows service?  By googling I've found this [forum post from 4 years ago](http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/12#556), I just want to be sure there isn't anything more up-to-date or any gotchas I should be aware of, before I spend too much time [yak shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving)

Comment: good point, except maybe there's a programmatic way to do it?  E.g. http://twapi.magicsplat.com/services.html.  But if it gets closed so be it, I'll ask it over on server fault (and maybe should search for it over there in the meantime)

Comment: If a commercial solution is fine, see this [tutorial showing how to run lighttpd as a Windows Service](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunLighttpdAsAService.html).

Comment: Dup: https://superuser.com/questions/491095/run-lighttpd-as-a-windows-service-for-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the WLMP project http://en.wlmp-project.net/

I use it for development, but have never tried it in production as i usually use linux servers.

Comment: The link is dead.